# How do I copy and then paste a text box in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to learn Inkscape. 
How can I copy and then paste a text box?

If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it converts it to an image instead.

Comment: You cannot copy paste a text box as it is (except when copying & pasting in Inkscape). You need to select & copy the text inside the text box & then you can paste it in Inkscape without being converted to an image.

Comment: What do you mean by *text box* anyway? From where are you copying it?

Comment: @Wzipmft If I go to the "A" icon and click, or if I click and drag to create a box. In both cases.

Comment: @chanduc, what you say seems the right answer, not just a comment

Comment: You create a text with the "A" icon, then select it with F1 > Ctrl+C > deselect with click in empty space > Ctrl+V and the result is a embedded image? 
It seems the behavior of Alt+B (Make a bitmap copy), there is a problem with the shortcut? just happens with the text box?

Comment: nukkio: it happens when I use the A and click and when I use the A click + drag a box. It happens when I use keys or if I go to the menu Edit > copy - paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This entry on the inkscape forum](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=13238) describes possible reasons why @bartovan's answer doesn't always work, and how to work around them.

1. copying from one inkscape document to another pastes as a bitmap. Cut&paste doesn't. So the workaround is to duplicate (Ctrl-D), then cut&paste.
2. on a Mac, cut&paste still doesn't work because of [a bug with X11](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Copying_and_pasting_in_Inkscape_creates_pixellated_images_instead_of_copying_the_vector_objects). The workaround is to modify the settings of X11: preferences ->
   Pasteboard: uncheck "Update Pasteboard when CLIPBOARD changes"

Answer (score 2):

If you select a text object in Inkscape with the selection tool (the arrow, F1), and then copy/paste it inside Inkscape (using eg. Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V), this produces a copy of the text object. This copy is itself also a text object.

You can also, instead of Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V, press Ctrl+D. This produces a duplicate (a copy) of the original object and places it exactly on top of it. You can do this with a text object, or any other object/path/...

Neither method produces (or should produce) a bitmap copy.

See also [Copying, Pasting, and Deleting Objects](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Copy.html) and [Creating Text](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Creating.html) in the [Inkscape User Manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.html) (not updated for Inkscape 0.91 but still accurate for the most part).